# Google analytics put "internal pages" as traffic coming from referrals

Tags: google-analytics

I have a technically 5 in 1 website:

the 5 links are:
www.purimas-lombok.com (landing page in HTML)
beachresort.purimas-lombok.com (wordpress 3.0.4)
sparesort.purimas-lombok.com (wordpress 3.0.4)
etc

In wordpress i'm using the plugin google analytics for wordpress.

In google analytics, I want those 5 website to appear like 1 website. I am using the setDomainName in the google code (see below). It's working but "sometimes" I still get the different websites in traffic source from refferals. I write "sometimes" because it's not all the time (between 0 and 4 max a day).

Do you have any ideas why it's like that ?
The code generated by the plugin is (almost) the same (see below)
I checked it's present on all pages with sitescanga.com and it's oke

Thank you

GA code:

#

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1']);
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', '.purimas-lombok.com']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
  var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
  ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
```

#

Code generated by the plugin in wordpress (for me is the same):

#

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
// Google Analytics for WordPress by Yoast v4.0.13 | http://yoast.com/wordpress/google-analytics/
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount','UA-17865992-1']);
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName','.purimas-lombok.com'],['_trackPageview']);
(function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
//]]></script>
```

#

Answer (score 1):

If people visited the site before you added the `_setDomainName` call then it's possible they have tracking cookies set for both the subdomain and main domain. For example, if you remove the function call then visit `beachresort.purimas-lombok.com` you will get a `__utma` cookie for `beachresort.purimas-lombok.com`. If you then add the code again and visit the site you will get another `__utma` cookie for `.purimas-lombok.com`.

When the GA JavaScript runs it will pick up the first set of cookies but when the user browses to another subdomain it won't recognize the cookies from the old domain and set new ones. For example, using the same situation as above, when you visit `sparesort.purimas-lombok.com` from 
`beachresort.purimas-lombok.com` it will look for cookies from `.purimas-lombok.com` but not find them because only the cookies from `beachresort.purimas-lombok.com` will be present on the browser (in fact the script won't even have access to them because of the cross domain security policy). When the new cookies are created, the `__utmz` cookie will be set with the new referrer (`beachresort.purimas-lombok.com`).

This problem should reduce over time but if it's a serious issue then you could write a script that removes the old cookies before running the GA code. The JavaScript would need to go through cookies on a page and delete ones named using the GA `__utm` scheme and linked to the full domain name.

Comment: Yes it seems to be decreasing. Let's wait a few days. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Hey, no it's not decreasing, last week we did some modif and it has increased the number of visitors from www.purimas-lombok.com up to 15 a day. No idea where it comes from... :(